# NSIS CopyFiles not working for .py files

Tags: python, nsis, file-copying

I am creating an installer for a Python program using NSIS. I have to copy the source files to C:\Program Files\Snakecharmer, so I am first making sure it is created, then copying the source files to C:\Program Files\Snakecharmer. There are three .py files that I am copying, plus `__pycache__`, and some other things.

The contents of `__pycache__` are copied,  but they do not stay in `__pycache__`, they are just copied loose into the directory.
The three .py files are not copied at all. Everything else copies correctly.

Here is my code

```
CopyFiles "$R0\SnakeCharmer.py" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\snakecharmerupdater.py" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\cobracrypt.py" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\__pycache__" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\Run_SnakeCharmer.bat" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\icon.ico" "$INSTDIR"
CopyFiles "$R0\SnakeCharmer.lnk" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
```

The first three are the .py files that didn't copy.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should not hardcode the all users startmenu path...

Comment: That's a temporary thing until I can find an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS uses [SHFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx) internally, there is no special handling of any file types. 
Just make sure the destination directory exists before you start the operation: `CreateDirectory "$InstDir"`

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) will probably give you some clues as to why it fails...